# How to add/edit content Custom Content item in theme

Tags: themes, dashboard

For my first wordpress/website, I purchased a WordPress theme. I can edit and add pages fine. My level of understanding is: to add a page I use the Pages | Add New button in the Dashboard.

Where I'm stuck: The theme also comes with a header that cycles through images and accompanying text. I can't figure out how to change the text. Are there files somewhere that I'm supposed to edit, or somewhere through the dashboard to enter this information, or has this been forgotten by the theme developer?

The examples for the header from the dummy content that's currently loaded appear in the Dashboard under Custom Content, but I can't see anything that links to the actual content, e.g., the text that's displayed. (I've pasted the code below, but I think it's all just style info).

```
[lnt_flexslider gallery_id="979" image_type="image-1980-600" slider_style="1" title_enable="1" title_font_size="70" title_animation_initial_position="25,15" title_animation_target_position="0,15" title_animation_duration="800" title_animation_easing="easeInOutExpo" subtitle_enable="1" subtitle_font_size="28" subtitle_animation_initial_position="25,55" subtitle_animation_target_position="0,55" subtitle_animation_duration="1000" subtitle_animation_easing="easeInOutExpo" pagination_style="1" pagination_position="inner" pagination_bottom_border="1"]
```

I'm a complete novice with these tools, so please let me know if there's some additional info that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a premium theme, it's hard to say how it is coded. Your best bet for support is to contact the author through channels that he/she has set up. They should be able to answer them better than we can since they built it.

Comment: Thanks! (Just starting out, I don't know what's standard and what's specific to the theme.)